# dotnet.exe locking SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.dll

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Good evening,

I am using the .Net Core 2.0 version from here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild on a 2.1 project in Jenkins with:

```
withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQubeMain') {
    bat "dotnet ${globals.SONAR_QUBE_MSBUILD_PATH}\\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:\"${globals.SONAR_QUBE_PROJECT}\" /d:sonar.host.url=${globals.SONAR_HOST_URL} /d:sonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths=\"XUnit.xml\" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=\"coverage.xml\"
}

bat "dotnet build --version-suffix ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

dir('test/mytestprojecthere') {
    bat 'D:\\OpenCover\\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"c:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:"xunit --no-build -xml XUnit.xml" -output:coverage.xml -oldStyle -filter:"-[*Tests*]*" -register:user'
}
withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQubeMain') {
    bat "dotnet ${globals.SONAR_QUBE_MSBUILD_PATH}\\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
}
```

It works the first build but on the next build it fails with:

```
Failed to create an empty directory 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\xxxxxxxx\.sonarqube'. 
Please check that there are no open or read-only files in the directory and that you have the necessary read/write permissions.

Detailed error message: Access to the path 'SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.dll' is denied.
```

and checking my windows server I can see multiple .Net Core Host Background process. If I kill these I can build again..

I readed about msbuild `/nodereuse:false` for MSBuild but seems is not working for the dotnet core version?

Answer (score 9):

We were just faced with this issue, and found out that it's related to dotnet's and msbuild's reuse of nodes that were left running by a previous multi-threaded build.

To avoid the problem, use either `/nodereuse:false` or `/nr:false` on your command line as the following:

```
msbuild /m /nr:false myproject.proj

msbuild /m /nodereuse:false myproject.proj

dotnet restore myproject.sln /nodereuse:false
```

Answer (score 6):

FYI @Nauzet opened an issue open for this in the Scanner for MSBuild repo: [#535](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/issues/535).

To summarise:

- the begin and end steps seem to run fine, and *dotnet.exe* shuts down as expected for those processes
- when building a complex solution, multiple instances of *dotnet.exe* are started and are do not shut down immediately when the build completes. The issue does not seem to occur on simpler solutions.
- the issue occurs if you trigger the build phase using *dotnet build* or *dotnet msbuild*
- workarounds: build using *msbuild* directly, or build using *dotnet build /nodereuse:false*

FYI the Scanner for MSBuild has a couple of custom tasks that are called during the build phase. These use the assembly that is being locked. There's nothing unusual about the custom tasks; they just read data from a file on disk. At this point, I'm not convinced it's an issue with the Scanner for MSBuild.

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue and running following command solved the issue.

```
dotnet build-server shutdown
```

This happens due to msbuild node re-use. we leave msbuild nodes alive with the intent of saving on startup time when doing consecutive builds.

It can turned off by setting an following environment variable too.

```
MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your pipeline script as shown below and it should work properly:

```
    withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQubeMain') {
    bat "dotnet ${globals.SONAR_QUBE_MSBUILD_PATH}\\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:\"${globals.SONAR_QUBE_PROJECT}\" /d:sonar.host.url=${globals.SONAR_HOST_URL} /d:sonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths=\"XUnit.xml\" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=\"coverage.xml\"

bat "dotnet build --version-suffix ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

dir('test/mytestprojecthere') {
    bat 'D:\\OpenCover\\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"c:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:"xunit --no-build -xml XUnit.xml" -output:coverage.xml -oldStyle -filter:"-[*Tests*]*" -register:user'
}

bat "dotnet ${globals.SONAR_QUBE_MSBUILD_PATH}\\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
    }
```

***UPDATE***

Here is a dotnet core app pipeline build script that I use, which works well without any issues:

```
bat "dotnet ${sqScannerMsBuildHome}\\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:yoursonarprojectkey /n:yoursonarprojectname /v:1.0 /d:sonar.host.url=%SONAR_HOST_URL%"
bat 'dotnet build'
bat "dotnet ${sqScannerMsBuildHome}\\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
```

Comment: does not work either. But I spent some hours trying things and I can say for sure the problem is caused by `dotnet build` after running the scanner. I assume is because my build is .Net Core 2.1 so I will wait for an update. The file seems to get unlocked after some minutes anyway. As this is my homelab and I am the only one using jenkins I can do this for now at the end of my pipeline: `bat "taskkill /FI \"MODULES eq SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.dll\" /FI \"USERNAME eq Jenkins\" /F"` but this is obviously working coz there will be only 1 build at the same time for me

Comment: I have a dotnet core app and I run this without any issues, so it’s definitely not dotnet build. Can you take out the open cover part and just do the app compilation and see? That’s what I have and it doesn’t have any issues.

Comment: Also what’s your project like? Any post build or pre build steps?

Comment: I have added my pipeline script. Please check

Comment: I tested it without opencover, without the unit tests, running on a different machine, removing projects from the solutions.. My solution have: library1 (netstandard2.0) library2 (netstandard2.0, dependency to library1) consoleApp1(netcoreapp2.1 dependency to library2) consoleApp2(netcoreapp2.1 dependency to library2) UnitTests (netcoreApp2.1 dependency to library2) I removed everything but library1 -> build correctly do not lock. Added library2 -> dotnet build locks the sonarscanner dlls for minutes.

Comment: Will test it out today and let you know.

Comment: Seems this got fixed after I split the solution in multiple ones to reference them as nuget packages instead projects.

Comment: ah okay, sorry I didnt get time to test this thats why I didnt respond back

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into it myself and "solved" it by running `dotnet build-server shutdown` as the first task in my build plan. That's not ideal for multiple reasons, one big one being that it'll likely cause issues if I attempt to run multiple .NET Core builds at once on the same machine. This does seem to be a bug in the scanner -- hopefully it'll be fixed soon.